# Check outgoing browser network calls using Cypress.io

Tags: browser, e2e-testing, cypress

On our site, we have Omniture calls that are fired when someone clicks on a link or takes some action. In Chrome DevTools in the network tab, you can see the network request being fired.

Is there a way for Cypress.io to capture outgoing network requests, so we can inspect/parse the URLs? The equivalent to this would be something like Browsermob proxy for webdriver set ups.  I want to use Cypress.io to tell it to click the link, but then I want to check the outgoing network request by the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found a workaround to our Omniture problem.  The request URL is stored in an Omniture property on an object attached to the browser window object.  Using cy.window() we can get the window object and access this property and use a node module (querystring) to parse the query string.

We could not find any native way in Cypress.io to inspect network requests.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use [`cy.route`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#Syntax) to wait on and make assertions against network requests:

```
cy.route({
  url:'*omniture.com*',
  method: 'POST',
  onRequest: (xhr) => {
    expect(xhr.request.body).to.eql('somebody')
  }
})
```

If the above doesn't work, it may be because the module is **using fetch**, which doesn't have native support yet. However, you can just have `omniture` fallback to XHR by **adding this to your `cy.visit()`**:

```
cy.visit('example.com', {
  onBeforeLoad: (win) => {
    win.fetch = null
  }
})
```

..

### or (as you mentioned) you can spy on the `omniture` global directly

You can use `cy.spy()` to `spy` on a global object on your site, here's an example:

```
cy.visit('example.com')
cy.window().should('have.property', 'omnitureRequest').then(win=>{
  cy.spy(win, 'omnitureRequest')
})
```

(the `should()` will wait for the object to be present before attempting to spy on it, since the `omniture` `<script>` tag could load `asynchronously`

Comment: Thanks for the information.  The code making the Omniture call is a black box to use.  As you said, we just want to spy on the request and make sure the request is formed correctly.  The property on the Omniture object is a URL string that needs to be parsed, so we probably still need that "querystring" node module.  We will see if any of these ideas work for us.

Comment: Somebody on my team tried the cy.route() solution, and the problem is that the method does not return any query parameters in the request.  Our Omniture request is a URL with query parameters.  So, I guess cy.route() doesn't account for query parameters.