# How to inspect and query outbound network requests with Cypress.io?

Tags: browser, e2e-testing, cypress

I'm trying to load a page, and then I want to use Cypress.io to check network requests that match `https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?*` and see the request a particular query parameter (there usually are at least 2 or more of such requests). In Chrome, if I wanted to manually check the networks requests of a page, I just go to the Network tab in Chrome Dev Tools and examine those requests. I was told in another semi-related SO question ([Check outgoing browser network calls using Cypress.io](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50820829/432089)) that I should be able to use

```
cy.route({
   url: '', 
   onRequest: (req) => { 
      // Some code in here
   } 
});
```

to automate this. However, when I set this cy.route() example up, with cy.server(), I don't see anything inside of this callback executing. The route to `https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?*` is checkmarked, but I see that one of the calls to `https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?*` returns 400 by the server in Chrome Dev Tools' network tab.  I don't see this 400 error if I hit the page normally.

It seems cy.route is for stubbing requests and responses.  I don't need to stub any requests or responses.   I just want to see and query the network requests going out without modifying them, just like Chrome dev tools does but automated. Does Cypress.io support this use case? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the `cy.wait()` to inspect the query params of the request that matched the `cy.route()`. Like this:

```js
cy.route("https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?*")
  .as("myAds");

cy.wait(@myAds)
  .then(request => {
    expect(request.url).to.match(/\?param1=true/);
  });
```

Also, if all you want is to manually see the query params, you can click on the `WAIT`:

[image]

And the console will show you the whole XMLHttpRequest where you can click to inspect the URL or other properties of the request and response:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I was able to work through my problem after asking a question on the Cypress github page.

Per the Cypress documentation, start cy.server(), then call the route, but pass an actual regex pattern into the url parameter (which wasn't documented).  I don't know what was wrong with the string glob version shown in the documentation, but an actual regex pattern caused the route to trigger.

```
cy.server();

cy.route({
  url: /gampad\/ads\?/,
  onRequest: (req) => {
     debugger;
     // Do checks here.
  }
});
```